# Turn values into column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have one table which contains some rows as below :

```
Sr.  Name         Product    Qty
1    Yogesh       ALB         1
2    Suresh       AMS         2
3    Yogesh       ALB         2
4    Mahesh       MAS         5
```

Now, i want display records as in below style...

```
Sr.    Name      ALB  AMS  MAS
1      Yogesh     3    0    0
2      Suresh     0    2    0
3      Mahesh     5    0    0
```

Comment: Can you post the code which you tried but not working?

Comment: you need column pivoting

Comment: You have shown ALB for Mahesh 5. How?? ALB should be 0 and MAS will be 5. Please refer my answer below

Comment: Number of distinct products is varying i guess. Serach for dynamic pivot, a lot of answers available.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT NAME,ISNULL(ALB,0) AS ALB,ISNULL(AMS,0) AS AMS,ISNULL(MAS,0) AS MAS
FROM
(SELECT  NAME,PRODUCT,SUM(QTY) QTY FROM TABLENAME
GROUP BY NAME,PRODUCT) A
PIVOT(SUM(QTY) FOR PRODUCT IN (ALB,AMS,MAS)) AS PVT
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN TRAN
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
  Sr Int NOT null,  Name  Varchar(255),  Product   Varchar(255) ,    Qty numeric
)

INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT 1 ,'Yogesh',  'ALB', 1 UNION All
Select 2  ,  'Suresh','AMS',2  UNION All
Select 3  ,  'Yogesh' , 'ALB',2  UNION All
Select 4 ,   'Mahesh','MAS',5

SELECT NAME,ISNULL(ALB,0) AS ALB,ISNULL(AMS,0) AS AMS,ISNULL(MAS,0) AS MAS
FROM (
    SELECT 
        (Name) as Name,left(Product,3)as Product, 
        Isnull(Qty,0) as Qty 
    FROM #temp
) as s
PIVOT (SUM(QTY) FOR PRODUCT IN (ALB, AMS, MAS)) AS pvt
ORDER BY Name

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below query.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) [Sr.],Name,ISNULL(ALB,0) AS ALB,ISNULL(AMS,0) AS AMS,ISNULL(MAS,0) AS MAS
FROM (
    SELECT Name,Product, 
        ISNULL(Qty,0) as Qty 
    FROM #temp
) as s
PIVOT (SUM(QTY) FOR PRODUCT IN (ALB, AMS, MAS)) AS pvt
```